# Get geometry value

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-8, voyager

Use Laravel 8 + Voyager + Swagger.
As in instruction https://voyager-docs.devdojo.com/v/1.1/customization/coordinates -
Use geometry type for points column

```
Schema::create('offices', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('address')->nullable();
            $table->geometry('points')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

But in API response got an error -

[image]

```
mb_convert_encoding(\DB::raw($this->attributes['points']), 'UTF-8'); - return 
"points": "\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000??\u0010??bR??Ng???D@",
```

Please help return the correct value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is being returned a Well-Known-Binary in the response?
I never worked with Voyager or Swagger, but, to work with coordinates in geometry fields in Laravel, one option to use is Accessors/Mutators.

A easy way to get the coordinates array is get the field as a GeoJSON, with the ST_AsGeoJSON function, and use a json_decode to return the coordinates field.

Something like this could return the coordinates:

```php
public function getPointsAttribute($value)
    {
        $result = DB::table('offices')
            ->select(DB::raw('ST_AsGeoJSON(points) as points'))
            ->where('id', $this->id)
            ->first();

        $geojson = \json_decode($result->points);
        return $geojson->coordinates;
    }
```

Comment: Not actual for now. But thanks a lot! It must be work!